# What can be done to fix LVM partition problems? Can't boot Windows after attempting to install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, partitioning

Attempted to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a separate partition from Win7 64-bit, but something went wrong with the install, and I am no longer able to boot from either the Win7 or the Ubuntu partition.  Further, I cannot boot the Win7 disk in order to effect repairs.

However, I am able to boot from the Ubuntu Live Disk.  Ubuntu recognizes the hard drive and the partitions but can not access its data.

When using the graphical interface in GParted, it appears that `sda5`, mount point Ubuntu-vg is superimposed on `sda2`, extended partition, and not side by side like one would expect.  `sda1` is a NTFS partition.

I have run Boot-Repair three times without a fix, and each time the result was different. Here is the most recent...

[broken link removed]

Being a newbie, I do not understand what these messages mean, or how to proceed without doing more damage.

I would like to be able to save the hard drive data, and boot to both Win7 and Ubuntu partitions through a boot manager.

Comment: Gparted cannot be used on LVM. Did you intend to erase Windows? You only have the Windows boot partition, not the "c: drive" partition? LVM is an advanced logical partition overlay over standard partitions. Not recommended for new users.

Comment: Thank you oldfred.  I did not intend to erase Windows, just wanted to add Ubuntu to an existing partition.  New user?  Got that right, as I did not even know there were advanced options.

Answer (score 3):

Your `/dev/sda2` is an *extended partition,* which means that it's a placeholder for one or more *logical partitions.* Thus, what you're seeing in GParted is normal. Furthermore, your Boot Repair output indicates that you're using a [Logical Volume Manager (LVM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) setup, which is why you can't directly access `/dev/sda5` -- it's further subdivided in an LVM way. None of this is cause for concern by itself, although an LVM setup is relatively advanced, and I think you've misconfigured it....

Your disk has SYSLINUX installed in the MBR, which is unusual but not necessarily wrong. (Ubuntu uses GRUB by default, not SYSLINUX.) When using an LVM, though, you normally have a separate `/boot` partition, but you don't seem to have one. Furthermore, your `/dev/sda1` is marked with a Linux partition type code (0x83), and it's of a reasonable size to be `/boot`; but Boot Repair has identified it as being NTFS and holding Windows boot files.

Overall, it looks to me as if you followed advanced instructions for Ubuntu installation but mis-read one or more steps and ended up with a rather mangled hash of things. My recommendation is to back up any user files (using a Windows emergency disk), wipe both your disks clean, and start again with re-installing both Windows and Ubuntu, but don't try to be as fancy in your installation. If wiping Windows is too painful to contemplate, then you could try recovering that and start over just with Ubuntu. You'd probably need to use `fdisk` to change the type code of `/dev/sda1` from 0x83 to 0x07, delete `/dev/sda5` and then `/dev/sda2`, and then ask on a Windows forum about recovery. ***Be careful, though!*** It's entirely possible that you'll dig yourself in even deeper -- for instance, if `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sde` change identities (as can happen), you might delete your NTFS partitions if you follow this advice.

Remember: Backups are your friends!

Comment: I will keep this answer because it is very helpful in understanding what is going on with the system.  There is one stumbling block and that is that the system does not recognize the Win7 DVD disk. So all I have is Ubuntu to work with. How did Syslinux get installed, I do not know.  This is the first I heard of it.

Comment: What is my next step?

Comment: If you can access your Windows partitions using the Ubuntu disc, you could at least back up your files that way. Of course, if you're having problems booting the Windows DVD, re-installing it using the same disc may be a problem....

Comment: Here's the funny thing . . . Ubuntu recognizes the partitions, but can not access any files. It's as though the drive is visible but locked?  Thank you again, Rod, for trying.

Comment: Windows will need with MBR partitioning a primary partition formatted NTFS with the boot flag and large enough for the install. You how as mentioned by Rod, sda1 as the small Windows boot partition, but partition table says it is ext4. Rod knows & uses LVM, but I do not recommend it for newer users unless you have to have fully drive encryption. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

Comment: Hello, oldfred ~ Without access to the Win7 install disk, how might I go about doing what you suggest?  I would be happy not to use LVM, and just start over but need to have the system recognize the Win7 DVD so first install windows, and at this point, I don't mind doing an entire drive format. Thank you for your suggestions and time, and I will read up on the link you included.

Comment: @BillR: It looks like you're running a hybrid UEFI/BIOS boot.  Would you try to turn UEFI back on (fastboot/secureboot) and then see whether you can boot Windows?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Early on I did UEFI on and ended up having to reset BIOS.  As of now, I had the HD formatted, and went forward from there.